# VMWare VMDK mapping to Windows Drive Letters

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, vmware, powercli

this code almost works, it maps VWare VMDK to windows drives. The code is not mine.

Among other info it will return "**DD-SERV-01_15.vmdk** for VM **MAIN** is Drive letter **G:**"

The script will prompt for credentials and proceeds to map however something goes wrong and only the last VM / Drive is is saved as output - I was hoping someone could take a look and update / fix the code so that it saves all output please?

Thanks.

```html
#Get VMware Disk Usage
# Created by Hugo Peeters
# http://www.peetersonline.nl
# VARIABLES
$Decimals = 1
$VCServer = "SERVERNAME"
# SCRIPT
# Connect to VC
Write-Progress "Gathering Information" "Connecting to Virtual Center" -Id 0
$VC = Connect-VIServer $VCServer
# Create Output Collection
$myCol = @()
# List Datastores (Datastore Name)
Write-Progress "Gathering Information" "Listing Datastores" -Id 0
$Datastores = Get-Datastore | Sort Name
# List vms
Write-Progress "Gathering Information" "Listing VMs and Disk Files" -Id 0
$VMSummaries = @()
ForEach ($vm in (Get-VM))
 {
 $VMView = $VM | Get-View
 ForEach ($VirtualSCSIController in ($VMView.Config.Hardware.Device | Where {$_.DeviceInfo.Label -match "SCSI Controller"}))
  {
  ForEach ($VirtualDiskDevice  in ($VMView.Config.Hardware.Device | Where {$_.ControllerKey -eq $VirtualSCSIController.Key}))
   {
   $VMSummary = "" | Select VM, HostName, PowerState, DiskFile, DiskName, DiskSize, SCSIController, SCSITarget
   $VMSummary.VM = $VM.Name
   $VMSummary.HostName = $VMView.Guest.HostName
   $VMSummary.PowerState = $VM.PowerState
   $VMSummary.DiskFile = $VirtualDiskDevice.Backing.FileName
   $VMSummary.DiskName = $VirtualDiskDevice.DeviceInfo.Label
   $VMSummary.DiskSize = $VirtualDiskDevice.CapacityInKB * 1KB
   $VMSummary.SCSIController = $VirtualSCSIController.BusNumber
   $VMSummary.SCSITarget = $VirtualDiskDevice.UnitNumber
   $VMSummaries += $VMSummary
   }
  }
 Clear-Variable VMView -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 }
# Loop through Datastores
ForEach ($Datastore in $Datastores)
 {
 # List vmdk files in datastore (vmdk Name)
 Write-Progress "Gathering Information" ("Processing Datastore {0}" -f $Datastore.Name) -Id 0
 $DSView = $Datastore | Get-View
 $fileQueryFlags = New-Object VMware.Vim.FileQueryFlags
 $fileQueryFlags.FileSize = $true
 $fileQueryFlags.FileType = $true
 $fileQueryFlags.Modification = $true
 $searchSpec = New-Object VMware.Vim.HostDatastoreBrowserSearchSpec
 $searchSpec.details = $fileQueryFlags
 $searchSpec.sortFoldersFirst = $true
 $dsBrowser = Get-View $DSView.browser
 $rootPath = "["+$DSView.summary.Name+"]"
 $searchResult = $dsBrowser.SearchDatastoreSubFolders($rootPath, $searchSpec)
 ForEach ($result in $searchResult)
  {
  ForEach ($vmdk in ($result.File | ?{$_.Path -like "*.vmdk"} | Sort Path))
   {
   Write-Progress "Gathering Information" ("Processing VMDK {0}" -f $vmdk.Path) -Id 1
   Write-Host "=============================================================================="
   # Find vm using the vmdk (VM Name)
   $VMRef = ($VMSummaries | ?{$_.DiskFile -match $Datastore.Name -and $_.DiskFile -match $vmdk.Path})
   "VMDK {0} belongs to VM {1}" -f $vmdk.Path, $VMRef.VM
   If ($VMRef.Powerstate -eq "PoweredOn")
    {
    Write-Host "VM is powered on" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
    $Partitions = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskPartition -ComputerName $VMRef.HostName
    If ($?)
     {
     $Disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $VMRef.HostName
     $LogicalDisks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $VMRef.HostName
     $DiskToPartition = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition -ComputerName $VMRef.HostName
     $LogicalDiskToPartition = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition -ComputerName $VMRef.HostName
     Write-Host "Read partition and disk information" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
     # Match disk based on SCSI ID's
     $DiskMatch = $Disks | ?{($_.SCSIPort - 1) -eq $VMRef.SCSIController -and $_.SCSITargetID -eq $VMRef.SCSITarget}
     If ($DiskMatch -eq $null){Write-Warning "NO MATCHES!"}
     Else
      {
      Write-Host "Found match:" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
      $DiskMatch
      # Find the Partition(s) on this disk
      $PartitionsOnDisk = ($DiskToPartition | ?{$_.Antecedent -eq $DiskMatch.__PATH})
      If ($PartitionsOnDisk -eq $null){Write-Warning "NO PARTITIONS!"}
      Else
       {
       ForEach ($PartitionOnDisk in $PartitionsOnDisk)
        {
        Write-Host "Disk contains partition" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
        $PartitionOnDisk.Dependent
        $PartitionMatches = $Partitions | ?{$_.__PATH -eq $PartitionOnDisk.Dependent}
        ForEach ($PartitionMatch in $PartitionMatches)
         {
         $LogicalDiskRefs = $LogicalDiskToPartition | ?{$_.Antecedent -eq $PartitionMatch.__PATH}
         If ($LogicalDiskRefs -eq $null)
          {
          Write-Warning "NO LOGICAL DISKS!"
          }
         Else
          {
          ForEach ($LogicalDiskRef in $LogicalDiskRefs)
           {
           $LogicalDiskMatches = $LogicalDisks | ?{$_.__PATH -eq $LogicalDiskRef.Dependent}
           ForEach ($LogicalDiskMatch in $LogicalDiskMatches)
            {
            Write-Host "Matching Logical Disk:" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
            $LogicalDiskMatch
            # Create Output Object
            $myObj = "" | Select Datastore, DSSizeGB, DSFreeGB, DSPercentFree, DiskFile, VM, HardDisk, DriveLetter, DiskSizeGB, DiskFreeGB, PercFree
            # List datastore name
            $myObj.Datastore = $Datastore.Name
            # Determine datastore size in GB
            $myObj.DSSizeGB = [Math]::Round(($Datastore.CapacityMB * 1MB / 1GB),$Decimals)
            $myObj.DSFreeGB = [Math]::Round(($Datastore.FreeSpaceMB * 1MB / 1GB),$Decimals)
            # Determine datastore free space (DS%Free)
            $myObj.DSPercentFree = [Math]::Round((100*($Datastore.FreeSpaceMB/$Datastore.CapacityMB)),$Decimals)
            # List disk file name
            $myObj.DiskFile = $vmdk.Path
            # List VM Name
            $myObj.VM = $VMRef.VM
            # Determine virtual hard disk / logical drive
            $myObj.HardDisk = $VMRef.DiskName
            # Report driveletter
            $myObj.DriveLetter = $LogicalDiskMatch.DeviceID
            # Report Size
            $myObj.DiskSizeGB = [Math]::Round(($LogicalDiskMatch.Size / 1GB),$Decimals)
            # Report Free Space
            $myObj.DiskFreeGB = [Math]::Round(($LogicalDiskMatch.FreeSpace / 1GB),$Decimals)
            # Calculate Percentage free space
            $myObj.PercFree = [Math]::Round((100 * ([int]($LogicalDiskMatch.FreeSpace / 1MB) / [int]($LogicalDiskMatch.Size / 1MB))),$Decimals)
            Write-Host "RESULT:" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
            $myObj
            # Add output object to output collection
            $myCol += $myObj
            }
           Clear-Variable LogicalDiskMatches -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
           }
          }
         Clear-Variable LogicalDiskRefs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
         }
        Clear-Variable PartitionMatches -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
       }
      Clear-Variable PartitionsOnDisk -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
      }
     Clear-Variable DiskMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     Clear-Variable Disks -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     Clear-Variable LogicalDisks -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     Clear-Variable DiskToPartition -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     Clear-Variable LogicalDiskToPartition -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     }
    Clear-Variable Partitions -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
   Else
    {
    Write-Host "VM is powered off" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
    }
   Clear-Variable VMRef -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
   Write-Progress "Gathering Information" ("Processing VMDK {0}" -f $vmdk.Path) -Id 1 -Completed
   }
  }
 }
# Disconnect from VC
Disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$False
# OUTPUT
Write-Host "==================================================="
Write-Host "==================================================="
$TotalDSFree = ($myCol | Select Datastore, DSFreeGB -Unique | Measure-Object DSFreeGB -Sum).Sum
$TotalDSSize = ($myCol | Select Datastore, DSSizeGB -Unique | Measure-Object DSSizeGB -Sum).Sum
$AverageDSFree =  [Math]::Round(100 * ($TotalDSFree / $TotalDSSize),$Decimals)
$AverageDiskFree =  [Math]::Round(100 * (($myCol | Measure-Object DiskFreeGB -Sum).Sum / ($myCol | Measure-Object DiskSizeGB -Sum).Sum),$Decimals)
Write-Host "Total DS Free: $TotalDSFree"
Write-Host "Total DS Size: $TotalDSSize"
Write-Host "Average DS Free Percentage: $AverageDSFree"
Write-Host "Average Disk Free Percentage: $AverageDiskFree"
$myCol | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation 'C:\TEMP\VMwareDiskUsage.csv'
```

Comment: Hi All - anyone able to assist with this? I am needing this desperately to document an existing system and I need to be sure I am touching the right windows volumes as they are mostly Thin Provisioned and the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `-Append` parameter to your export-csv, so it does not overwrite the last entry:

```
$myCol | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation 'C:\TEMP\VMwareDiskUsage.csv'
```