# Mapping VM Drive to Corresponding VMDK file

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, esx

- Problem:

  Lets say i have a VM with three storage LUNS attached to it through SCSI
  VMFS stores each drive as a individual VMDK files.

  1. C:(one_c.vmdk)
  2. D:(two_d.vmdk)
  3. F:(three_f.vmdk)

In ESX host these there vmdk files are stored in /container_name/vm_name/

```
Is there any way of mapping,given (disk serial number or disk id) and vmdk files location can we figure out to which vmdk file this Drive maps to?
```

Note: i have gone through this link
[VMWare VMDK mapping to Windows Drive Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962018/vmware-vmdk-mapping-to-windows-drive-letters). But not that keen to do using scripts

Comment: You must query the guest OS because it is free to change the driver letter mappings. If you don't want to use scripts or WMI (why not?) then take a look at [`guestInfo.guestDiskInfo`](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-65/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.vm.GuestInfo.DiskInfo.html). It provides you with the sizes and names of the disks mounted on the VM. You can correlate the size with the VMDKs as you see them on the ESXIs (assuming sizes are unique). Note that things like [dynamic disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx) will break this.

Comment: ya we can do that using script as well.But Trying for a simpler way instead,                                                                                               
Another way of doing this,vmware stores a mapping of scsi-vmdk mapping in .vmx files as below                                           scsi2:6.fileName = "Demo_Today_11.vmdk,as i know the location vmdk file i can grep the .vmx file for scsi2:6.filename                                                                 for a given volume letter(ex:G:)as input i need to get scsi2:6 or associated scsi id,Do you know how?

Comment: The script that you linked to in your question does this mapping: `$DiskMatch = $Disks | ?{($_.SCSIPort - 1) -eq $VMRef.SCSIController -and $_.SCSITargetID -eq $VMRef.SCSITarget}`. Note that this query must be performed by the VM itself because the guest OS can change the drive letter mappings as it sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReconfigVM_Task for the virtual machine that has those disks attached.
You need to pass virtualMachineConfigSpec which, as the name implies, specifies the virtual machine's configuration. Under it you will find virtualDeviceConfigSpec

What you want to do is:

- Fetch the existing virtualMachineConfigSpec of your VM
- Locate the relevant virtualDeviceConfigSpec for your disk
- Edit the **backing info** of that disk

  - Change the file name to the correct path (starting from the datastore)
  - Unset the fileOperation (to avoid creating a new disk there)
- Execute ReconfigVM_Task on the VM with the updated spec

Please consult the doc for more specific instructions

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/converter-sdk/conv50_apireference/vim.VirtualMachine.html#reconfigure